# Servicio que toma una captura de pantalla del estado de otra aplicación.¿Necesita root?

Tags: android, permisos, adb, screenshot

La aplicación en sí lanzará otra, y deberá capturar la salida de pantalla de esta aplicación objetivo. Me gustaría poder evitar que dicha aplicación necesite permisos root, pero sospecho que para monitorizar la actividad de otra aplicación necesitará de ellos.

¿Con el modo ADB, podría situar el dispositivo con permisos ampliados para capturar dicha actividad sin utilizar permisos root?
¿Dependería de un PC para activar el servicio?

Comment: De acuerdo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462944/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-other-app-programmatically-without-root-permission) (en stackoverflow en inglés) es bastante complicado por no decir que imposible sin ser root.

Comment: Viene indicado todas las posibildades a probar, ciertamente es complicado, pero me ha solucionado todas las dudas de un plumazo. Estuve buscando en inglés también, pero se mezclaba las condiciones en las que se iba hacer la screen, no encontré este fabuloso artículo con los experimentos de este usuario. Gracias.

Comment: Tu pregunta me parece pide opiniones, revisa [ask]. En realidad necesitarías permisos Root y para obtener una imagen de otra aplicación tal vez no sea tan sencilllo